# how to add background image to matplotlib figure or figurecanvas

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pygtk

I am working on a project where I am using PYgtk to build UI which make use of matplotlib library for plotting purpose. Plot window is packed in UI using PYgtk scrolled window container widget as the actual plot will be very big in size.

I want to put an image as a background to figure or figurecanvas, but not to subplot. I want subplot to scroll but not background image.

I am trying with slider option in matplotlib. but still no success.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue?